# Not a valid object name: 'master'

Tags: git, git-branch, git-bash

I created new directory **test** and **CD** into it
Creating new Repository into it :

```
git init
```

Creating one text file **test.txt** and one directory with another text file inside it **mydir/newfile.txt** :

```
echo "Hello" > test.txt 
mkdir mydir
echo "hello" > mydir/newfile.txt
git add test.txt
git add mydir/newfile.txt
git commit
```

After these steps when i want to have a branch by writing :

```
git branch new_branch
```

I have the error :

> fatal: Not a valid object name: 'master'

Comment: I suspect you do not have any commit in your repository. What does `git log` show?

Comment: fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for everyone.
I just had to define my email and username by these two lines and everything worked :

```
$ git config --global user.name "username"  
$ git config --global user.email "example@example.com"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with this

```
git commit -m "initial commit"

git push -u origin
```

It will work. if you are facing any issues please share your error, so that we can find the issues and help you.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the same commands as you did. Instead of git commit, you could type

```
git commit -m "Initial check-in"
```

And, after that master branch would be set. And, then you could type 'git branch new_branch' and it would work as expected.

The reason why it didn't work for you is that git commit didn't work for you and so the initial branch wasn't set. If you want to use 'git commit', then type some message in it. After that, it should work too.

Comment: I had also the same message . Nothing different .